# pentaho Configuring for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, pentaho

I use pentaho BI community version 4.5 stable and want to configure to postgresql. According the book **pentaho solutions** switch to mysql, I edited the following xml file, replace hsql with postgresql
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate"/>
the file as follows:

```
tomcat\webapps\pentaho\META-INF\content.xml
pentaho-solutions\system\hibernate\hibernate-settings.xml
pentaho-solutions\system\applicationContext-spring-security-jdbc.xml
```

When I run the BI server, something is wrong:

```
WARN [PackageManager] Unresolved dependency for package: org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.cdc.CdaModule
WARN [PackageSorter] A dependent module was not found in the list of known modules.
ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: permission denied for relation datasource
ERROR [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledDataSourceSystemListener: PooledDataSourceSystemListener.ERROR_0002 - Unable to get datasource object.
org.pentaho.platform.api.repository.datasource.DatasourceMgmtServiceException: ERROR_0004 - Hibernate Error occurred during retrieving the datasource to the database
......
```

What about this question?
How can I get more doc or books about pentaho? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've got this error in there:

```
ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: permission denied for relation datasource
```

Check that the user you're using to connect to postgres with has appropriate permissions in your database - you can verify that outside of pentaho using psql for instance. If you check your database logs you should see a more detailed message that gives the query that was trying to run that generated the error.

Comment: Accept answer to close the topic as it refers to others that it's still open.